# Static C# variable, throw an error because of a database connection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, static

I'm wondering if there's a way to overcome this situation:

I have an static class with an static variable called let's say

```
static string[] Cities = GetCities();
```

And `GetCities` obtains from a database all the cities. The problem is that I'm getting an error with `GetCities` because the data server sometimes is not available, and this error doesn't disappear even if the server is available again. 

I think that this is because the variable Cities is created only once...

Comment: you can make some initializer method which will try to connect to db and then save needed information to `Cities`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think that this is because the variable Cities is created only once

This is correct: there will be only one call of `GetCities()`; if it fails, there will be no other calls. To fix this problem, change `Cities` to a read-only property, and cache the results of `GetCities()` when you do get the results.

```
static string[] cachedCities = null;
public static string[] Cities {
    get {
        return cachedCities ?? (cachedCities = GetCities());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going with this answer

Comment: @robertwolfheart You are welcome! If you are no longer looking for an improved solution, you can accept the one you find helpful to indicate that you've got a solution. This would also earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't do database access while initializing the type.

Consider introducing a caching mechanism for your database queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

Static initialization only occurs once per class. When an exception occurs during static initialization, the CLR stores the exception. Future uses of that class will automatically rethrow the same exception, rather than triggering any reinitialization. You cannot change this behavior.